# How to show $ |f*g|_{1} \le |f|_{1}|g|_{1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

> I have to show $ \|f*g\|_1 \le \|f\|_1\|g\|_1$.

Comment: You can see a proof of a more general statement in any book that talks about convolutions. It is called Young's inequality. There is also a famous  inequality that is less general than Young's, namely that $\|f*g\|_p \le \|f\|_1 \|g\|_p$, which can also be found in many places.

Comment: See e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Young's_Inequality_for_Convolutions

Comment: @AhmedHussein To use Young inequality to show the inequality the OP is interested in is really taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $f,g: \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$. Observe:

$$\int_{\Bbb R^d} \left| \int_{\Bbb R^d} f(x-y)g(y) dy \right|dx \le \int_{\Bbb R^d} \left[ \int_{\Bbb R^d} |f(x-y)||g(y)|dy \right] dx$$

Using Tonelli's theorem, the RHS is equal to

$$\int_{\Bbb R^d} \left[ \int_{\Bbb R^d} |f(x-y)||g(y)|dx \right] dy$$

Which after rearrangement becomes $\|f\|_1 \|g\|_1$. Hence $f * g \in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ and $\|f * g\|_1 \le \|f\|_1 \|g\|_1$